# Entity Framework C# Insert Data russian encoding problems

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using an EDM model in my project.

When I insert russian words in the database via a post request I get `??????`

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public string DescEdit(FormCollection formValues)
{
    var CurrentUserPhoto = User.Identity.Name;
    string x = Request.Form["id"];
    Int64 id = Convert.ToInt64(x);
    photos upPhotoDesc = photosRepository.GetPhotosById(id, CurrentUserPhoto);
    upPhotoDesc.description = Request.Form["value"];
    photosRepository.Save();

    return Request.Form["value"];
}
```

1. In the database all charset are set to utf-8
2. In the layout page content enc type is utf-8

Database code:

```
CREATE TABLE `photos` (
  `id` bigint(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `done` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `imgsmall` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `imgcrop` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `imgmiddle` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `imgbig` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `full_size` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `permission` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `userlogin` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `rating` smallint(5) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `indx_photos_1` (`id`,`userlogin`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Well, *something* in the chain of events must be doing a lossy conversion to/from an obsolete character set. You will need to identify that something and make sure that it uses Unicode.

Comment: Shot in the dark: Are you sure the database actually contains question marks? Maybe only the thing you’re using to *look at* the database displays question marks.

Comment: i'm trying to understant where is this "something" for 2 hours already :))

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with the debugger and made sure that `Request.Form["value"]` still contains the correct Cyrillic?

Comment: @Timwi - Yes, im sure. PhpMyADmin show and MySQL-Front

Comment: @Timwi - return Request.Form["value"] return to me the correct russian string, so I think that the form value is ok

Comment: the post data sent in urlencode-like string.... may be this is the problem?..

Comment: If you've not seen it already I wrote this article recently on common characterset problems in PHP/LAMP http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/

Comment: thanks for articul! But still not working... :(((

Comment: please check my answer at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632240/entityframework-update-or-insert-chinese-or-non-english-text/24765790#24765790

Comment: please check my answer at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632240/entityframework-update-or-insert-chinese-or-non-english-text/24765790#24765790

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add `charset=utf8` to the connection string of Entity Framework
Here is a working add node:

```
<add name="photostorageEntities"
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Photos.csdl|res://*/Models.Photos.ssdl|res://*/Models.Photos.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=ServerIP;User Id=UID;password=PASS;Persist Security Info=True;database=photostorage; Charset=utf8&quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this - saved me a headache!

Comment: adding charset=utf8 causing "nested transactions are not supported" error :(