# EntityFramework update or insert Chinese or non-English text

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Actually before i did not use framework or linq, just type in sql statement with Sqlcommand class, i type in `insert into table values(N'sample')`
actually i donot know what is N, but it works for Chinese and other Language, otherwise, it will insert some question mark.

But when i use EntityFramework,this kind of framework always insert some question mark, can i ask how to tackle the issue.

N means Unicode?
Can you give me one example that EntityFramework use that sort of thing?

Comment: BTW, I tested EF with Hebrew in it works just fine. Does Chinese included in the unicode?

Comment: It may depend on how the database looks like. If you are using SQL Server - are your columns nvarchar or nchar? In EF the string property needs to have Unicode set to true. Are you using CodeFirst or Database/Model first?

Comment: You need to provide more information about your mapping and database.

Answer (score 5):

1. in .edmx Table, select column -> check its properties and set unicode to true
2. re-generate table if you are working in Code First Apporach
3. check your database table, it should be nvarchar or ntext datatype

this way EF will save unicode characters.

[image]

Comment: this solved my problem... from "????" text to real working strings Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had exact same problem for Nepali Language. I had to convert the datatype of sql server column from varchar to nvarchar and then refresh my *.edmx file in entity framework mapping. Then it worked fine.

varchar(255) => nvarchar(255)

varchar(MAX) => nvarchar(MAX)

Right click on that table mapping in edmx file and refresh. Save the changes.

Comment: This works for me, I changed type from  varchar to nvarchar and updated the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the language packs installed on the server that holds sqlserver for Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

we just changed the datatype to nchar() or nvarchar and it worked. It was able to store the data in any language other then English.