# Azure WPF Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, azure

Can I change the encoding of **SQL**? 
I enter text in **Russian**, but instead the text is displayed: '???'

Comment: What is your database collation set to? I believe you want utf8 to handle Russian characters

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS , yes i need convert to utf8

Comment: What is the field type you are trying to write to? varchar? If this is not a production database you could try changing that field to nvarchar and it should handle the Cyrillic (unicode) characters.

Comment: I use NVARCHAR. that's why I thought that it encoded.

Comment: Can i convert text to utf8 in c# and send it to DB?

Comment: Take a look at the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632240/entityframework-update-or-insert-chinese-or-non-english-text  - Check that unicode is enabled in the EF field property

Comment: I executed it: Cyrillic_General_CI_AS