# Unable to get Encoded strings from EntityFramework LINQ Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, character-encoding

I have my EntityFramework model(edml) hooked up with OracleClient. I am using LINQ queries on my Entity model object to access data. The problem I am facing is that when the data has an encoded character say "ä", my LINQ query result set shows it as a normal decoded string "a". I need to maintain the character encoding.

Here are the things that I have done so far and none of them have worked so far.

1. I have set the Unicode property as true as mentioned in the link below.

   [EntityFramework update or insert Chinese or non-English text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632240/entityframework-update-or-insert-chinese-or-non-english-text)
2. I tried setting CharSet=utf8 in my ConnectionString as mentioned in the below link and I end up getting the Error. "Unknown connection string parameter 'CharSet'". I tried all possible Combination (charset, CharSet etc). None worked

   [Entity Framework C# Insert Data russian encoding problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889438/entity-framework-c-sharp-insert-data-russian-encoding-problems)

When I access the data using OracleDataAccess object instead of EntityFramework, I get the data as expected. The below sample gives me the correct data.

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(@"SELECT * FROM EMP", connection))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connectin Complete");
        command.BindByName = true;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        Console.WriteLine("Reading Data");
        OracleDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        //  dr.Read();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.Count(); j++)
            {
                sb.Append(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString());
                sb.Append("\t\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Displaying the Data");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

All I want is to get the data as-is from DB from EF. Any help would make my life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the "Unicode=true;" option in your [connection string](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection~ConnectionString.html). Does this help?