# Inserting Japanese Characters To SQL Server database

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem that when I am trying to insert a Japanese word to my database. It insert them, but when I check the word, it looks like this: "??????"

So I explored in stackoverflow and tried many solution but failed and I still have same problem. Here is my code if someone can help:

Here is the word I enter into a text box:

```
ケンガンアシュラ
```

Database shows it as:

```
????????????
```

Model:

```
 [Display(Name = "Alternative Name")]
 [StringLength(200)]
 public string Alternative_Name { get; set; }
```

At SQL Server it has a datatype of

```
nvarchar(200)
```

Here is my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h4>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Alternative_Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })</h4>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Alternative_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Alternative_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to update it using migration and changed Unicode to true:

```
  AlterColumn("dbo.Post", "Alternative_Name", c => c.String(maxLength: 200, unicode: true));
```

But nothing works, the database keeps showing it as `?????`.

**UPDATE**: In my case the solution simply in the model builder or model class which explain the relation btw tables and attributes the Unicode was set to false so I changed it to true and solved:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .Property(e => e.Alternative_Name)
            .IsUnicode(true);
```

Comment: Whatever is passing that string to the database needs to prefix the string with an N. Compare `SELECT 'ケンガンアシュラ', N'ケンガンアシュラ';` Does this thing generate a SQL command at some point? What does it look like? Can you intercept it and edit it? Maybe you should be calling a stored procedure instead of letting this thing generate ad hoc SQL.

Comment: Prefix values with N while inserting.

INSERT INTO INFORMATIONS(SOME_TEXT) VALUES(N'your chars')

Comment: I'm using Linq and simply i don't handle the value when i add to db since i'm using asp mvc entity so i just add the model to db with all the values once

Comment: i think this link is helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632240/entityframework-update-or-insert-chinese-or-non-english-text

Answer (score 1):

String in .Net are by default unicode which should pass the Japanese to the DB as NVarchar

Use data annotations on your model to tell.net what the type is using Column(TypeName ="NVarchar")]

```
Column(TypeName ="NVarchar")]
[Display(Name = "Alternative Name")]
 [StringLength(200)]
 public string Alternative_Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In The SQL Server DataBase you should be at the column that you want to insert data in it set type as NVARCHAR(3000).

Answer (score -1):

The column should be in nvarchar

```
create table yourTableName(yourColumnName nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO yourTableName(yourColumnName) VALUES(N'ケンガンアシュラ');
```

Comment: Already my attribute type nvarchar! and i don't add it as string to database , I Adding it like this : model.post= japaniesWord;

Comment: try this model.post= N'japaniesWord' .
I mean model.post = N'ケンガンアシュラ'

Comment: Not work .. also i assign the that i got from view to the model .. simply i got a model of data then i assign it like this model.post=oldmodel.japaword;

Comment: the string type should be nvarchar. If yes then try this 

model.post= 'N' + oldmodel.japaword

Comment: if this model.post= 'N' + oldmodel.japaword  does not work then. I think you need to convert it to nvarchar in c# before you do this.

Comment: It's not work ,, how to convert it in c# a string to nvarchar ??

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/60963a47-bc8b-41b1-b1f4-2be12955649e/convert-string-to-nvarchar50?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Comment: Thanks , i found the solution ... i appreciate your help