# C# Entity Framework Migrations adding weird characters to string

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have strings in my MsSql  database with `nvarchar` column type. My seed method sample is  this:

```
protected override void Seed(Sro.Models.ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        Konu iyimi = new Konu { isim ="ıyımıdır", lastAktifTime = DateTime.Now, konuUrl = "iyimi", };
        db.Konu.AddOrUpdate(iyimi);
    }
```

when I execute the seed method  some characters "ç, ö" are okay but  "ı" character saving as "ý" in database, for example "ıyımıdır" appears "ýyýmýdýr". I tried differen sql servers but the result is same. 
By the way there's no problem with website queries. When I try to add new row when debugging it is okay. It doesn't make any sense to me. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you checked sql query by profiler?

Comment: No, I didn't, do I need to ?

Comment: Is the C# source file utf-8 encoded?

Comment: for some reason it was converted to ANSII or something else. I changed file encoding with Notepad++ now it works.

Comment: File->Advanced Save Options  Encoding: Unicode(utf8)

Answer (score 1):

Add  "Charset=utf8" to entity connection string.

[Entity Framework C# Insert Data russian encoding problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889438/entity-framework-c-sharp-insert-data-russian-encoding-problems)

Answer (score 0):

Try add 'N' before string eg: `UPDATE TableName SET Name = N'śćżas' WHERE Id = 0`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30801185)