# Difference in Where clause and foreach look up in C# entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I have a piece of code:

```
var component = (from components in dataContext.Component select components)
                    .Where(x => x.Name.ToString().Equals(componentCode));
```

where `Component` is very simple [object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPNTz.png).

In mysql database table **(encoded in utf8 - utf8_unicode_ci)**

I have record such as: **szkło 3mm** (with polish character **ł**).

> When I'm trying to find this record with the code above I get nothing.

Records without polish characters works fine.But when I'm doing it with `foreach` I get the result:

```
var component = (from components in dataContext.Component select components);
foreach(Component comp in component)
{
    if (comp.Name.ToString().Equals(componentCode))
        componentPrice = (decimal)comp.Price;
}
```

Is there a way to get the result with just a linq code without iterating through table.?

Comment: Any reason you are using `varchar` and not `nvarchar` for the `Name` column?

Comment: What is the datatype of Component.Name in your DB. Is it nvarchar?

Comment: Type of Name is varchar. And no, there is no reason to use varchar.

Comment: Interesting that you are having the opposite problem that most people have. The linq query is doing a sql compare (which is failing apparently), whereas the for loop is forcing the execution of the query into memory, then doing a .Net comparison. Usually the sql comparison is more forgiving because it is case insensitive by default.

Comment: the problem seems to be the encoding, I kind of doubt EF can calculate a query with a parameter containing such symbols. Try to set the encoding of your column to unicode (either via connection string, fluent API or Data annotation).

Comment: I tried changing varchar into nvarchar and still the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found solution - I have added "Charset=utf8" in the connection string and it works.
Solution found in topic:
[Entity Framework C# Insert Data russian encoding problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889438/entity-framework-c-sharp-insert-data-russian-encoding-problems)